# What is the FIREWALLD equivalent to IPTABLES -NOTRACK

Tags: iptables, firewalld

I recently converted to centos 7 and so far I am beginning to like the simplicity of zones in my firewall structure, however I can't seem to find a configuration parameter for `firewalld` like the `iptables` "NOTRACK" which essentially ignores the status of the incoming connections. In other words I need a stateless `firewalld` setup in order to keep up with the volume of Queries coming into my DNS Caching server.

This is the syntax I was using with `iptables`:

```
iptables -t raw -I OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j NOTRACK
iptables -t raw -I OUTPUT -p udp --sport 53 -j NOTRACK
iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -p udp --dport 53 -j NOTRACK
iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -p udp --sport 53 -j NOTRACK
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

ip6tables -t raw -I OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j NOTRACK
ip6tables -t raw -I OUTPUT -p udp --sport 53 -j NOTRACK
ip6tables -t raw -I PREROUTING -p udp --sport 53 -j NOTRACK
ip6tables -t raw -I PREROUTING -p udp --dport 53 -j NOTRACK
ip6tables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -I INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -I OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't remember the syntax for marking the traffic as NOTRACK, but doing it in the raw table is correct.

You'll need a rule like
`iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NOTRACK -j ACCEPT`
to actually let the traffic through. (and a corresponding rule for IPv6).

Comment: Henrick,  does the iptables command still apply to firewalld? . I read that the back end still uses iptables and netfilter.  To clarify I am using firewalld. . Thanks.

Comment: Netfilter is the kernel part doing the actually filtering on any Linux (since kernel 2.2 or 2.4 - I don't remember anymore). iptables is a fairly low-level (and my preferred) tool for configuring netfilter, Firewalld (which I don't know anything about) is probably just another tool.

Answer (score 1):

Use [direct rules](https://firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewalld.direct.html):

```
Raw

# firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 raw PREROUTING 0 -p udp --dport 53 -j NOTRACK
# firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 raw PREROUTING 0 -p udp --sport 53 -j NOTRACK
# firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 raw OUTPUT 0 -p udp --dport 53 -j NOTRACK
# firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 raw OUTPUT 0 -p udp --sport 53 -j NOTRACK
```

Add `--permanent` to the above once you've tested that the rules work.

For more info, see [How can I disable connection tracking (conntrack) with firewalld?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2991381)